# Как правильно написать и оформить SELECT?

Tags: python, sqlite3

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=['subscribe'])

def subscribe(message: Message):

connect = sqlite3.connect('users6.db')

cursor = connect.cursor()

cursor.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS login_id(
id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
user_name TEXT NOT NULL UNIQUE,
last_name TEXT NOT NULL UNIQUE)""")

connect.commit()

people_id = message.chat.id
user1_name = message.chat.first_name
last_name = message.chat.last_name
cursor.execute(f"SELECT id FROM login_id WHERE id = '{people_id}'")
cursor.execute(f"SELECT user_name FROM login_id WHERE user_name = '{user1_name}' ")
cursor.execute(f"SELECT last_name FROM login_id WHERE last_name = '{last_name}' ")
data = cursor.fetchone()
if data is None:
    users_id = message.chat.id
    first_name = message.chat.first_name
    last_name1 = message.chat.last_name
    cursor.execute("INSERT INTO login_id VALUES(?, ?, ?);", (users_id, f'{first_name}', f'{last_name1}'))
    connect.commit()
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Ты подписался_ась на рассылку✅')
else:
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Ты уже подписан')
```

Как правильно написать SELECT как написан у меня INSERT?
Чтобы не вызывать 3 раза.

Comment: `"SELECT 1 FROM login_id WHERE id = ? and user_name = ? and last_name = ?", (people_id, user1_name, last_name)`